# ngMap/Google Maps Api v3: call function when shape edited

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I have an issue with ngMap and a shape.

A shape can have the two different properties, draggable or editable.

The editable adds a point in the middle of the circle to drag it around. And 4 points on the outside to change the size of the radius.
As can be seen here: EDITABLE
https://ngmap.github.io/#/!shape_circle_with_current_position.html

The draggable can be seen here: DRAGABLE
https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/events.html

```
<ng-map zoom="11" center="current-position">
    <shape draggable="true" on-dragend="someFunction()"></shape>
</ng-map>
```

With draggable I can use the "on-dragend" directive(is this a directive?) when I drag it around.
But I dont know what directive I can use with editable="true".

```
<ng-map zoom="11" center="current-position">
        <shape ??on-edit??="someFunction()" editable="true"></shape>
</ng-map>
```

I want to call a function when the Shape has been edited so I can update my "radar" and "lat", "lon" values.
Something like on-edit , on-change? I tried to brute force a little bit already :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "on-center_changed" for the position of the circle and:
"on-radius_changed" for the radius.

Documented here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#InfoWindow

```
<ng-map zoom="11" center="current-position">
        <shape on-radius_changed="vm.radiusChanged()" on-center_changed="vm.centerChanged()" editable="true"></shape>
</ng-map>
```

Comment: @choz If you provide more information, I might be able to help you as it works just fine for me.

Comment: I've raised the issue on [github](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/637). And I also provided the plunker there.. You can check it out..